# How to pop the navigator two pages back?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to leave the current screen and navigate back to the second to last screen.

```dart
void leaveStatefulWidget3(){
  Navigator.pop(context);
}

// StatefulWidget 2...

// StatefulWidget 3 {....}
// the current one (where the navigator is now)
```

My app has navigated from the first screen to 2, and then to 3.

I need to leave or `Navigator.pop(context)` the  `StatefulWidget 3` to  `stateFull 1`.

NOTE : I have complete access to my `leaveStatefulWidget3()` method from `StatefulWidget 3`, but don't know how to specify the route to use `Navigator.pop(context)` in `leaveStatefulWidget3()`.

When I use `Navigator.pop(context)` directly from the first widget it leaves `stateFull 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `Navigator.pop(context)` twice

Comment: thanks it work but the context is for first screen How does it left for third screen ? can u explain

Comment: context is not just about the page you are in, it 's a location in you widget tree. can access other I guess

Comment: thanks you .. i even did not try it . i just ask question direct without to test it because i was sure it will never accept .. but well u make me test it and it work thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could easily use 'popUntil' with 'pushNamed'

Add the route settings with route names when pushing,
like this.

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, < StatefulWidget name >);
```

Then, at the recent widget ( in your case, its stateful_widget 3 )

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/"));
```

*Here you can use widget name or '/'
*'/' will bring you back to the startup widget

Or , if this is always from certain widget to very first one
You could directly use

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```